# Explicitly mention the consequences of the different user destruction options

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, spam

There are two options when destroying a user:

[image: Moderator actions modal showing the various destroy user reasons.]

While it might not look that way from the dialog, the consequences of the two options are somewhat different. Both remove the user and all their posts, but the "spam or nonsense" option also feeds into the network-wide spam prevention system.

While this has been mentioned a few times to the moderators, there are always new mods and if you missed the original announcement it is easy to miss that there is actually a difference to these options.

The moderator tools should always explicitly spell out their consequences. In this case they should mention which reasons feed into the spam defense system.

Comment: If the account meets the criteria spelled out in the reason, why would it matter what happens to it after you destroy it? I'm trying to grasp what someone would do differently if this were spelled out.

Comment: Or, better put, is your concern that new moderators aren't using this option to deal with spammers because it's not discover-able enough?

Comment: @TimPost Yes, discoverability is the big reason. It would also help for abusive users, which don't exactly fit the text but where you still want to have them blocked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "mod" menu on user profiles has had some changes since this question was posted. The most recent one was rolled out yesterday, and it now looks like this:

[image: "Moderator menu" in user profiles, with the "Moderator actions" subsection selected. Under the section's heading, there's a "Learn more about these actions" paragraph, which contains a link. Options shown to "Annotate," "Clear sessions," " Delete user," "Destroy user (includes content)," "Send moderator message (includes suspension)," and "Contact Community Team." The "Destroy user (includes content)" option is selected, showing a text box for additional information, and two sub-options for explaining why the user profile is being destroyed: "User primarily posts spam or nonsense," and "Majority of user's content violates our terms of service."]

The "Learn more" link near the top of the box links to a new help center article that explains the different actions' consequences in detail:  [What actions are available in the "Mod" menu on users' profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/mod-user-actions)  (mod-only link; see `/help/mod-user-actions` on a site where you have a diamond to access the article).

Differentiating between all options' consequences in the modal itself would be a bit unwieldy, so we opted for putting detailed information in a help center article instead.

---

P.S.: Thanks to Catija for doing most of the CM-side work on this. I just took it past the finish line <3

Comment: Glad this update got rolled out! <3

Answer (score 7):

The spam system was designed to not be thought about. It was designed to just work off of signal that you ordinarily give the system, and not cause you to think twice about an action you might take. Making it operate more or less silently behind the scenes was a key design constraint for getting all involved to actually implement it.

At the time, spam and mega-trolls were a *colossal* problem, a chronic source of complaint, and the reason that several great contributors ultimately left the sites that they loved due to harassment by others. *I wish that I could have gotten this implemented silently, so that nobody had to think twice about it*. It didn't work out that way, we *had* to let folks know that we addressed the issue because we were (quite frankly) tragically inept at dealing with it previously.

Asking for the reason why an account was about to be roasted was part of getting the system implemented, we were wasting a lot of signal by *not* asking moderators why they were taking certain actions. I thought for quite some time of the reasons why you'd want to destroy a user. There are two, really:

- They're a spammer / troll and you want them and their content gone
- Every single thing this user has posted is either wildly inappropriate, plagiarized, or horrible for some other means.

The difference is, in the first it's the *user* you mostly want gone, along with whatever they've typed on the site and in the second, it's mostly the contributions that you want to clean up, while getting rid of the source. A lot of people reviewed the reasons, and they were whittled down, refined, shortened and clarified probably a dozen times before it went out.

I think I'm going to go back to having three reasons there, but need to think on it a bit:

> - This user was created to post spam or nonsense, and has no positive participation
> - This user was created to cause disruptions or harass other users, and is no longer welcome on the site
> - The majority of this user's content violates our terms of service by being either (a) plagiarized or (b) wildly inappropriate as viewed by an average person

Note that you *have* a 'no longer welcome' option in the 'delete' menu, I put it there because there *are* cases where such a user would be out of the scope of 'destroy' due to the amount of rep they have (rare, but it does happen).

I could easily just keep it at two reasons, and indicate that the first one is equally good for trolls as it is for spammers, but we *might* want to weight them differently.

I can see the discover-ability and potential decision paralysis, and for the *most* part, new mods have been pulling the right levers.

I'm not going to do anything yet, I have to think about it, but I can see what you're getting at.